# Android wifimanager enable network seems to enable wrong network

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I have made an android app which on startup gets the current wifi network and connects to a different one. At least that is what it is supposed to do:

```
wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
OldNetworkID = wifiInfo.getNetworkId(); //save current network
WDTNetworkID = wifiManager.addNetwork(wificonfiguration); //add new network
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(WDTNetworkID, true); //enable new network and disable all others
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

When I debug I can see `wificonfiguration` contains the right SSID (the SSID of the new network).

After `addNetwork()` I see that `wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()` contains this new network with the right SSID and the same networkID as `WDTNetworkID`. At this point the network is enabled.

But after `enableNetwork()` instead of `WDTNetworkID` enabled and the rest disabled I see that `OldNetworkID` is enabled and the rest is disabled.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image: This is what it looks like]

I have added a picture of a couple of watches while debugging.
You can see here that the old network is enabled and the rest is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the device the app is running on is android 5.1.1.
As it states in the documentation of `enableNetwork()`:

> **Note:** If an application's target SDK version is [LOLLIPOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#LOLLIPOP) or newer, network communication may not use Wi-Fi even if Wi-Fi is connected; traffic may instead be sent through another network, such as cellular data, Bluetooth tethering, or Ethernet. For example, traffic will never use a Wi-Fi network that does not provide Internet access (e.g. a wireless printer), if another network that does offer Internet access (e.g. cellular data) is available. Applications that need to ensure that their network traffic uses Wi-Fi should use APIs such as [bindSocket(java.net.Socket)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket(java.net.Socket)), [openConnection(java.net.URL)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#openConnection(java.net.URL)), or [bindProcessToNetwork(Network)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You just need add this line to your code. i had same problem, adding this line help me.conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

```
//After sleep a little milliseconds then check exist connection with this code:
try {
 Thread.sleep(3000);
 Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "You are connected to " + 
 mainWifimanagerObject.getConnectionInfo().getSSID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```